# Text Item data copy from other

Tags: oracleforms

I have two text items. Both of them do not have any value. When I added some text in first text item same data should be reflected to other one. So how to do this.

Thnx in advance

Comment: Can you please show some examples of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need always the same value in both items then you should use mirror items also known as synchronize with item property.
This will display the same value in both items.

Answer (score 0):

If you need some kind of logic for the synchronizing of the two items then you can use the When-Validate-Item trigger of the master item to populate the child item. But if the need a simple synchronizing without any logic then the item property 'Synchronize With Item' (as already stated by nigthfox79) is the right way to go.